# Python: Drag a scipy.stats object through a python function

Tags: python, function, statistics, scipy

I'm trying to assign a `scipy.stats` `rv` object in a function and return it:

```
def Prior():
    priorObj = norm(loc=1, scale=1)
    return priorObj
```

How can I keep the `rv` object including its methods and access it via

> Prior.pdf()

and

> Prior.cdf(0.5)

Do I have to copy the object in order to be able to pass it through a python function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've created your function you'll have to call it and assign the returned `rv` object to something as below.

```
def Prior():
    priorObj = norm(loc=1, scale=1)
    return priorObj

prior = Prior()

prior.pdf(0.5)
# etc
```

If you don't call the function and assign it to something and instead try to use the function itself then you'll be trying to access the `pdf` method of the function itself which will raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Thank's a lot. The parentheses in my function call were missing. I can skip the step prior = Prior() and call Prior().cdf(0.5) right away.

Comment: Yes you can but if you then call `Prior().cdf(0.6)` you'll have to re-run the function `Prior`, whilst if you save it to `prior` then you'll have it available. Depends on your use case I suppose.